# python quad: integrating over one variable while treating other variable as constant?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am doing simple integration, only thing is that I want to keep 'n' as a variable. How can I do this while still integrating over t?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math as m
y = lambda t: 3*t
T = 4      #period
n = 1
w = 2*np.pi*n/T

#for odd functions
def integrand(t):
    #return y*(2/T)*np.sin(w*t)
    return y(t)*np.sin(n*w*t)
Bn = (2/T)*quad(integrand,-T/2,T/2)[0]
print(Bn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using quad, you cannot. Perhaps you're looking for *symbolic* integration like you would do with pen and paper; [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) can help you here:

```py
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol("x")
t = sympy.Symbol("t")
T = sympy.Symbol("T")
n = sympy.Symbol("n", positive=True)

w = 2 * sympy.pi * n / T
y = 3 * t

out = 2 / T * sympy.integrate(y * sympy.sin(n * w * t), (t, -T/2, T/2))
print(out)
```

```
2*(-3*T**2*cos(pi*n**2)/(2*pi*n**2) + 3*T**2*sin(pi*n**2)/(2*pi**2*n**4))/T
```

If you want to evaluate the integral for many `n`, [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) can help:

```
import numpy as np
from quadpy import quad

y = lambda t: 3 * t
T = 4
n = np.linspace(0.5, 4.5, 20)
w = 2 * np.pi * n / T


# for odd functions
def integrand(t):
    return y(t) * np.sin(np.multiply.outer(n * w, t))


Bn = (2 / T) * quad(integrand, -T / 2, T / 2)[0]
print(Bn)
```

```
[ 2.95202424  4.88513496  4.77595051  1.32599514 -1.93954768 -0.23784853
  1.11558278 -0.95397681  0.63709387 -0.4752673   0.45818227 -0.4740128
  0.35943759 -0.01510463 -0.30348511  0.09861289  0.25428048  0.10030723
 -0.06099483 -0.13128359]
```